# Roth 401k rollover into Roth IRA: How are earnings handled?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, roth-401k, fidelity, rollover-direct

I have a Roth 401k from a prior employer and I want to roll it into a Roth IRA. For simplicity, let's assume there are no pre-tax employer match funds in the 401k, only my after tax contributions and earnings on those contributions.

I know my contributions can be rolled into the Roth IRA with no problem, but what about the earnings in the Roth 401k? Common sense and most of what I read indicates earnings should be rolled over with no adverse effects.

I find conflicting information on this, and so far have not found a straight answer. When I go through the rollover procedures on Fidelity's website, the transaction preview shows my contributions headed for my Roth IRA, and the earnings splitting off into a traditional IRA, or I am given the option to pay taxes on my earnings and convert them to Roth. This does not seem correct to me.

Quote [from IRS](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Retirement-Plans-FAQs-on-Designated-Roth-Accounts):

> The amount contributed to a designated Roth account is includible in
>   gross income in the year of the contribution, but eligible
>   distributions from the account (including earnings) are generally
>   tax-free.

Is "generally tax-free" pretty loose?

Does anybody have a first-hand experience doing this kind of rollover? Bonus points if you managed to do it from a Fidelity-managed Roth 401k.

Comment: Just a follow up on this. I ended up giving up on the fidelity webapp, biting the bullet and calling fidelity. As Jared suspected, Fidelity had an error in their system, showing Roth earnings splitting off into a traditional ira. Calling to do the rollover was required. Roth 401k to roth ira rollover was executed with no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So first off, this should be handled as a rollover, not a "distribution".  Rollovers have different rules than distributions.  Therefore, your quote from the IRS does not apply.  The simple answer is **your entire Roth 401k amount can rollover to a Roth IRA with no penalties or taxes.**  If Fidelity is routing it differently then they're having an error in their system that you may need to speak with someone about.

Comment: +1 The OP says that for simplicity "let's assume there are no pre-tax employer match funds in the 401k". The employer match, if any exists and is vested, _will_ roll over into a Traditional IRA that  can be converted to a Roth IRA after paying taxes on the money.

Comment: A rollover cannot happen if the 401k does not have any eligible distribution options, so I think the quote still holds water. To your first sentence, I indicated the intention to rollover and did not mention any other ways of taking a distribution such as withdrawal. I get that the simple answer is as you stated, I can make that more clear in my question if you think it is necessary. I'm really looking for actual experience or documentation to back up my own research and any research from the person answering.

Comment: @zerpsed - What?  You do **not** take a distribution when you do a rollover.  A distribution is you taking money to use, not to go to another qualified retirement account.  Just call Fidelity and tell them you want to roll your Roth 401k into a Roth IRA and they'll walk you through it.

Comment: @Jared what you are talking about is a withdrawal.

Comment: @zerpsed A qualified distribution is a type of withdrawal.  There are also non-qualified distributions, which is another type of withdrawal.  IRS docs don't really use the term withdrawal since it would be ambiguous which of these you were referring to.

Comment: @Jared That's fair, should not have used the word withdrawal. I guess keeping a distribution would be more correct.

Comment: @zerpsed Yeah, not trying to be pedantic, just is helpful if you know the terminology they use so you'll know which sections apply (i.e. distribution vs. rollover).  Anyway, don't forget to accept the answer unless you're waiting on additional feedback (if so either comment or clarify the quesiton).

Comment: @Jared I will wait a while for additional feedback. The second part of the question was also important to me. Wondering if anyone has actual experience with using Fidelity's webapp to do this. I hate calling companies. I'll accept at some point though.

Comment: Would you perhaps have a link to support your answer?

Comment: I have a followup question about how the funds rolled over into the Roth IRA are treated. As I understand, withdrawal of rollovers in a Roth IRA is not taxable, and a penalty only applies within 5 years to the amount "that you had to include in income" (which according to your answer should be none). Does that mean I can rollover a Roth 401k (including contributions and earnings) to Roth IRA, and immediately withdraw it, without any tax or penalty?

Comment: @user102008 - Rollover funds are treated entirely as a deposit for Roth IRA withdrawal purposes.  Makes rollovers a very valuable way to fund the Roth IRA.

Comment: @Jared: Do you have a citation on that? It seems to contradict what Publication 590 says.

Comment: @user102008 Actually, I believe there is a 5-year rule applied to it, but it is treated as contribution after that.

Comment: @Jared: It is always the case that conversions & rollovers are no different penalty-wise from contributions except for the 5-year rule. My point was that according to the 5-year rule, the penalty does not apply to the part of conversions/rollovers that were not includible in income when converted/rolled-over. So according to this, you an rollover a Roth 401k to a Roth IRA and immediately withdraw all of it, without any tax or penalty. Do you agree with this?

Comment: @user102008 - so finally found a reference about how you can withdraw your contributions immediately: http://www.mymoneyblog.com/can-i-really-withdraw-my-roth-ira-contributions-at-any-time-without-tax-or-penalty.html

Comment: @Jared: Right, that's about contributions. But we are really wondering about rollovers.

Comment: @user102008 I ended up needing to know the answer to your question before withdrawing money from my Roth IRA. It took considerable research of IRS publications to find the answer. I did find it though; no citation at this point. The 5 year rule does not apply to contributions only but does apply to earnings. You actually have to look at the statements for your 401K to determine the contribution/earnings split that funded your Roth IRA via rollover. You can rollover and then immediately withdraw the contribution portion from the roll penalty free; not so with the earnings portion.

Comment: @zerpsed: For distribution from Roth IRA, it matters whether the money is counted as "contribution", "conversion or rollover", or "earnings". My issue was which of those 3 categories a rollover from Roth 401k from Roth IRA falls into. I initially thought it might fall into "conversion or rollover", but found a federal regulation (26 CFR 1.408A-10 A-3) that clarifies that it falls into "contribution" and "earnings" instead, with the amounts of contributions and earnings migrated over from the Roth 401k. So that answers my question.

Comment: @user102008, yep that's it; all there is to it. Fairly simple in the end but took a lot of effort to get there.