# If you rollover a Roth 401k to Roth IRA and immediately withdraw it, is there any tax or penalty?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, rollover, roth-401k, withdrawal

According to the accepted answer to [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/roth-401k-rollover-into-roth-ira-how-are-earnings-handled), when you rollover a Roth 401k which contains contributions and earnings, to a Roth IRA, you don't pay any taxes.

Suppose you then withdraw from the Roth IRA the amount that was rolled over (assuming there is nothing else in the Roth IRA). Is there any tax or penalty on this withdrawal?

From what I can see in Publication 590, there is no tax on Roth IRA withdrawals of contributions or rollovers/conversions; only on earnings. As for the penalty (10% additional tax), for rollovers/conversions, [it only applies](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch02.html#en_US_2013_publink1000231064) within the first 5 years after the rollover/conversion, and only on "any amount attributable to the part of the amount converted or rolled over (the conversion or rollover contribution) that you had to include in income (recapture amount)". Since there was no tax on the rollover (from the linked answer above), no part of the rollover had to be included in income, and thus, there should be no penalty.

Is this correct? Any citations would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're thinking that by rolling over your Roth 401(k) to Roth IRA the whole amount becomes "contribution". That is not so, you're not losing the characteristics of the amounts within the account. The grouping rules of [Sec. 408A](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/408A) still apply, and you still need to separate contributions from earnings.

See specifically this text in the statute:

> Any distribution allocated to a qualified rollover contribution under
>   clause (ii)(II) shall be allocated first to the portion of such
>   contribution required to be included in gross income.

So no, you do not get to withdraw earnings tax free just because you rolled them over. As a general rule, when you read the IRS pub 590 - consider your rollover from Roth 401(k) as if it was a roll-over from a different Roth IRA. But do consult a tax professional (EA/CPA licensed in your state) as there are intricacies.

---

You seem to be confused about various holding period limitations ("5-year rules") for Roth IRA. There are two:

1. You cannot have qualified distributions unless you had the Roth IRA for at least 5 years.
2. You cannot withdraw earnings on amounts from *conversions* without penalty (additional 10%) within the first 5 years of conversion.

These are two separate and unrelated limitations. Since you're talking about Roth 401(k) roll-over - the second one doesn't apply, since you didn't do any conversion. The first one does. See [this article](http://www.kitces.com/blog/understanding-the-two-5-year-rules-for-roth-ira-contributions-and-conversions/) for in-depth discussion on this.

In any case, you pay **tax** (with or without the additional 10% penalty) on distribution attributed to earnings, unless it is **qualified** distribution.

Comment: "You're thinking that by rolling over your Roth 401(k) to Roth IRA the whole amount becomes "contribution"." No, I'm thinking the whole amount becomes "rollover". In Publication 590, amounts in the IRA are described as "contribution", "rollover/conversion" or "earnings".

Comment: @user102008 yes, I get it, whatever you call it, you think that by rolling over it becomes miraculously tax free. It doesn't. The pub explains the grouping rules quite well. For roll-overs you first allocate the taxable portion (which is everything not reported on your W2 for your Roth 401(k)), and then the non-taxable portion (which is all the rest).

Comment: You quote the grouping rules for distributing rollovers from a Roth IRA. These grouping rules are relevant because early distributions of the taxable portion of the rollover has a penalty within 5 years. That is not relevant to this question because no part of the rollover was taxable.

Comment: @user102008 you're confusing things. 5 years limit is on **qualified** distributions. You cannot get **qualified** distributions for 5 years.

Comment: No, you're confusing two different things. You are thinking of conditions on what a qualified distribution is; you need to have opened a Roth IRA for 5 years (regardless of when you contribute), and you need to be at least 59.5 (or meet some other exception). However, this is not what I'm talking about. There is a penalty on non-qualified withdrawals of rollovers and conversions from a Roth IRA within 5 years of the rollover/conversion, but only to the taxable part: http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch02.html#en_US_2013_publink1000231064

Comment: I think I understand your confusion. I edited my answer to address that.

Comment: That is exactly what I said. If you read my comment, it says exactly that those two 5-year things are unrelated. Anyway, figure 2-1 in Publication 590 also says that the part of non-qualified distributions "allocable to earnings" "may be" taxable. The thing is, how do you define "allocable to earnings" (e.g. conversions are not "allocable to earnings" but where is that defined; and why are rollovers from Roth 401k not included)?

Comment: I also looked at Form 8606, Part III of which is the thing that calculates the taxable part of a non-qualified Roth IRA distribution. Line 24 is about the basis from conversions and 401k rollovers, and is subtracted from the distribution. The instructions say to enter rollovers from 401k on that line. I cannot find anything that says rollovers from Roth 401k should be excluded from that line.

Comment: @user102008 the basis in your 401k rollover is the amount reported on W2 (i.e.: the amount you've paid tax on).

Comment: It's not basis *in* the rollover. It's basis in the Roth IRA *from* conversions and rollovers. The instructions say to include all conversions and 401k rollovers.

Comment: @user102008 yes, but you're not talking about a conversion or 401k rollover. You're talking about *Roth* 401(k) rollover. The basis for this rollover is not the whole amount, only the amount you paid tax on - the one reported on W2.

Comment: Would the answer be different if you rollover a pre-tax 401(k) to a traditional IRA, then convert to Roth? My understanding was you'd have to pay taxes on the conversion, but in 5 years you could withdraw everything tax-free.

Comment: @CraigW no, the answer wouldn't be significantly different. The only difference is the amount considered "basis". In the scenario you describe, you would still pay taxes when you withdraw because the withdrawals are fist attributed to earnings. Unless it is a qualified distribution.

Comment: @littleadv: The 8606 instruction actually says "Also include on line 24 any amounts rolled over from a qualified retirement plan to a Roth IRA for 2008,
2009, and 2011 to 2013 reported on your Form 1040..." What we call Roth 401k is a type of "qualified retirement plan"; just a "designated Roth account" within such a plan. Also, I believe that the entire sum of the rollover is reported on the 1040, but not taxed.

Comment: @user102008 what you call what is irrelevant. I agree, the instructions may look ambiguous. But that would not be a defense for you in case of an audit or a court case. The fact that you may interpret the instructions the way you want is irrelevant since the instructions have no legal authority. I quoted the statute for you, and it is in fact pretty clear.

Comment: @littleadv: But you have not cited any passage from a statute that says the withdrawal (or any part thereof) is taxable.

Comment: @user102008 read again the quote. You're refusing to accept what it says because you don't want to, not because you don't understand.

Comment: @littleadv: I understand it very well. I don't think you read it. You have a quote that says the stuff that is taxable is allocated first. It doesn't say what is taxable.

Comment: @user102008 what's taxable doesn't change during the rollover. When you roll things over - part of it is taxable (the earnings), and part is not (the basis). **this doesn't change**.

Comment: Can I get a clarification here? Let's say I put $1 into a Roth 401(k), and it earns another $1. I rollover $2 to a Roth IRA. I wait 5 years and it earns another $1. Is the dispute about the second or third dollar?

Comment: @CraigW second. user102008 is convinced that since he rolled it over, it lost its characteristic of taxable earnings for non-qualified distribution. That is incorrect.

Comment: For the record I don't know who's right here. But I have seen a lot of sites that suggest (perhaps incorrectly) the entire conversion amount is tax free. For example [here](http://www.madfientist.com/traditional-ira-vs-roth-ira/) and [here](http://www.kitces.com/blog/understanding-the-two-5-year-rules-for-roth-ira-contributions-and-conversions/). [Here](http://www.mrmoneymustache.com/2011/11/11/how-much-is-too-much-in-your-401k/) it says "At this point, you can withdraw all of the principal (but not the gains yet, no big deal), penalty-free!", but I'm not sure which gains they refer to.

Comment: Note the above examples referring to the slightly different case of rolling over from pre-tax 401(k) to Traditional IRA, then converting to Roth, whereas the question asked about rolling over from Roth 401(k) to Roth IRA.

Comment: @Craig the entire conversion amount is indeed tax free. Because the basis is the entire conversion amount - you paid tax on it when you converted. So the calculation is the same, as I said. The only difference is what is the basis. In case of Roth 401k - the basis is what is reported on W2 (and subsequently on 1040). In case of conversion - the basis is what is reported on 8606 (and subsequently on 1040).

Comment: Okay, you're right. I just found [26 CFR 1.408A-10](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.408A-10) A-3 which says that a Roth 401k to Roth IRA rollover is allocated to contributions and earnings, and not to "rollovers and conversions". This is something that was not explained in Publication 590.